# Umbraco upgrade from 7.2.8 to 7.3.0 broke the website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, umbraco7

I am trying to umbraco upgrade from 7.2.8 to 7.3.0 and getting below error after update :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I have tried to upgrade "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration" but it also doesn't help.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.0.0" newVersion="1.8.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

[image]

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll` is in the bin folder when you build the website?  If it isn't 2.0.0.0, your project probably has a reference to the wrong version somewhere.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0

Comment: That's your problem then, at run time it can't find the 2.0.0.0 DLL.  Right mouse click on your project, choose 'Manage Nuget packages for solution', search for Windows Azure and see if there are two different versions installed.

Comment: I have added binding for this and it has version 1.8.0.0. Where it is trying to find 2.0.0.0  dll? two different version are not installed .

Comment: Sounds like you're still at the wrong version, something within your project obviously depends on version 2.0.0.0 else you wouldn't be getting the error `Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager -Version 2.0.0` in package manager console and see what the output is.  [See here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/2.0.0)

Comment: I have also added screenshot which show all azure packages installed on my solution.

Comment: After installation this package I am getting this error :
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: assemblyFile

Comment: The package on your screenshot `Windows.Azure.Storage` relies on `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager (version >= 1.8.0)` [according to this page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/4.3.0), so that's probably why you have that version installed.  But it should be safe to update the version of the 1.8.0 package.

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Nuget installed?  If not, update that too within Visual Studio or by downloading it.

Comment: Latest nuget package 3.4.4.1321 installed on my machine for VS2015

Comment: Latest version of [Nuget is v3.5.0](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)

Comment: ``After installation this package I am getting this error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: assemblyFile...`` do you mean that you get other error message after you upgrade Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager to v2.0.0 (or higher version)?

Comment: Yes, this error seems related to this package 
  <package id="ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2" version="3.4.3" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: Do you have the Umbraco.Cms.Core Nuget package in your project?  Is that on the 7.3.0 version?

Comment: From [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504898/umbraco-upgrade-from-7-2-8-to-7-4-3-throwing-error-for-azure), it seems that you have fixed the ''error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: assemblyFile...'' by upgrading “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager” package to 2.0.1. You could write it as a answer in this thread for help others resolve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed below steps to fix this issue while upgrading umbraco version

1. Umpdate umbraco package

   > Update-Package UmbracoCms -Version 7.3.0
2. Upgrade Window Azure package from 1.8.0 and try to run the project

   > Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager - 2.0.1
3. After this run the project and umbraco will do configuration changes automatically. after successfully upgrade website run successfully